# Proving whether function-series $f_n(x) = \frac{(-1)^nx}n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm asked to prove whether the following function-series on $E$ with values in $Y$ converges pointwise/uniformly/absolutely.

$$E = [-1, 1], Y= \Bbb{R}$$

$$f_n = \frac{(-1)^nx}n.$$

What I have tried so far: Using [direct comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) test to find a convergent series and then using the [Weierstrass M-Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) but I can't find any solution to this problem.

Comment: you dont find any solution to any of the asked questions? Observe that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k x}k=x\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}k$$ What about it pointwise convergence? And it absolut convergence?

Comment: @Masacroso Good idea. Does that imply that $f_n$ is not converging absolutely (harmonic series) but convering uniformly and therefore pointwise?

Comment: Yes that's it !